# Как установить библиотеку SFML для C++ на CLion?

Tags: c++, sfml

Мне необходимо установить библиотеку SFML для C++ на CLion, так как Visual Studio мне не подходит по некоторым причинам. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Библиотека прописывается в `CMakeLists`, как и любая другая. В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: Более того, на сайте `SFML` есть [гайд](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php), как собрать библиотеку с помощью `cmake`

Comment: Tocic , проблема в том что данный гайд не помогает, и появляются разного рода ошибки.

Comment: Разного рода? Какого? Приведите тексты ошибок в вопросе. Как сообщество может вам помочь, если не знает в чём у вас проблема?

Comment: CacaoBoy есть хороший Гайд на сайте https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/06/02/Creating-an-SFML-project-on-Mac-OS-using-CLion-and-CMake.aspx сам ставил пару дней назад ,там норм рассказано

Comment: [Как собрать библиотеку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1007651/206435)