# Как подключить библиотеку sfeMovie?

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

Я хочу подключить библиотеку sfeMovie (для отображения видео) к проекту. Делаю всё по инструкции: http://sfemovie.yalir.org/latest/start.php

Дошёл до пункта Build. После долгой сборки получил следующие файлы: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке bin нашёл файлы .lib и .dll [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и подключил их к проекту в ручную через свойства проекта. (Я так понимаю эти библиотеки там лежат для воспроизводства тестовой программы, и возможно они не полные. Также есть ещё точно такие же библиотеки в папке FFmpeg-binaries/lib,  но в ней нет необходимого .lib файла sfeMovie-d.lib). В итоге при попытке вывода видео, проект запустился, но видео не отобразилось м в консоле вылезли ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Причём в тексте ошибки почему-то выводится обрезанное название файла, который я хочу открыть (на самом деле должно быть video.avi)

Подскажите в чём проблема?

Вообще в инструкции есть последний пункт (Installation), который я не выполнил, потому что не пойму что в нём нужно сделать.

З.Ы. 
И ещё. У меня была уже готовая программа, в которой я тестировал запуск видео. Я убрал из неё всё ненужное и оставил только код необходимый для запуска видео. При запуске выскочило исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы:

```
#include <SFML/Config.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <sfeMovie/Movie.hpp>


int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 840), "SFML works!");

    sfe::Movie movie;
    movie.openFromFile("movie/video.avi");
    movie.fit(200, 0, 450, 800);
    movie.play();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

        }

        movie.update();

        window.clear();
        window.draw(movie);
        window.display();
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну теперь понятно, `movie.openFromFile("movie/video.avi");`, замените на `movie.openFromFile(u8"movie/video.avi");`. Все.

Comment: @ヒミコ ничего не изменилось

Comment: Тогда пропишите полный путь к файлу с `u8`.

Comment: @ヒミコ я тестирую программу, в котором есть другой код, помимо написанного выше и там есть код, который нужен для вывода фотографии на экран. Так вот, при попытке прописать полный путь, программа почему-то пытается открыть файл с фотографией, а не указанное видео (в тексте ошибки название этого файла с фотографией также обрезано) Точно так же происходит если указать вообще неправильный путь к видео.

Comment: Как бы... https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3mD1.jpg

Comment: @ヒミコ ну это понятно, что код рабочий. У меня что-то в подключении неправильно. Вы как библиотеку sfeMovie подключали?

Comment: Собрал, установил, подключил. Устанавливать не обязательно. Я так подозреваю что вы не правильную библиотеку положили к исполняемому файлу, который не совпадает с `lib` файлом, на который вы линкуетесь.

Comment: @ヒミコ а с какой папки вы брали .lib файлы? с такой же как у меня? насколько сильно у вас вообще последовательность установки от моей отличается?

Comment: Из директории в которую была установлена библиотека https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSsqD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окей, напишу полную инструкцию.

Начнем с загрузки `git` репозитория.

1. Установите [`git`](https://git-scm.com/) *(Если не установлен)*
2. Запускаем командную строку от имени администратора.
3. Клонируем репозиторий **SFML** `git clone https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git && cd SFML`
4. Собираем и устанавливаем `SFML`:

```
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. && cmake --build . --config Debug && cmake --build . --config Release && cmake --install . --config Debug && cmake --install . --config Release && cd ..\\..
```

5. Клонируем репозиторий `sfeMovie`: `git clone https://github.com/Yalir/sfeMovie.git && cd sfeMovie`
6. Собираем, и устанавливаем:

```
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake -DSFML_ROOT="c:/Program Files (x86)/SFML/" .. && cmake --build . --config Debug && cmake --build . --config Release && cmake --install . --config Debug && cmake --install . --config Release && cd ..\\..
```

Теперь идем по пути `C|D|E:\\Program Files (x86)\\SFML`, любуемся на установленный `SDK`

Так же по расположению `C|D|E:\\Program Files (x86)\\sfeMovie` находится `SDK` `sfeMovie`.

Comment: спасибо за инструкцию. Я так понимаю это 32x разрядные библиотеки, тк VS ругается на неправильную разрядность. А как установить 64x версию?

Comment: А зачем вам 64 бита? Прежде чем делать такие приложения, подумайте, на самом деле ли они вам нужны.

Comment: можете всё же подсказать, как установить x64 версию, а то при компиляции под x86 ошибки вылазят.

Comment: Добавьте к команде сборки, не установки, один параметр:  `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64`